# Need help setting up an alias in bash

Tags: bash, git-bash

I work with languages often and I have to change them via an export command for my tests to read them, so I want to set up a simple alias to run a change on them quickly, I have:

```
alias country="export COUNTRY="$1""

alias locale="export LOCALE="$1""
```

basically, I want to enter in bash to set the country like so, and have it perform the command that I normally type which is export COUNTRY=GB, and export LOCALE=en-GB:

```
country GB

locale en-GB
```

Comment: Aliases don't take positional parameters, write a function and then alias the function.

Comment: ...or don't use an alias at all, and *just* write a function.